# Correlate one set of vectors to another in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a set of vectors (readings from sensor 1, readings from sensor 2, readings from sensor 3 -- indexed first by timestamp and then by sensor id) that I'd like to correlate to a separate set of vectors (temperature, humidity, etc -- also all indexed first by timestamp and secondly by type).

What is the cleanest way in numpy to do this? It seems like it should be a rather simple function...

In other words, I'd like to see:

```
> a.shape 
(365,20)

> b.shape
(365, 5)

> correlations = magic_correlation_function(a,b)

> correlations.shape
(20, 5)
```

Cheers,
/YGA

P.S. I've been asked to add an example.

Here's what I would like to see:

```
$ In [27]:  x
$ Out[27]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0, -1],
       [-2,  0, -2],
       [-3,  0, -3],
       [-4,  0.1, -4]])

$ In [28]: y
$ Out[28]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 0.1]])

$ In [28]: magical_correlation_function(x, y)
$ Out[28]: 
array([[-1.        ,  0.70710678,  1.        ]
       [-0.70710678,  1.        ,  0.70710678]])
```

Ps2: whoops, mis-transcribed my example.  Sorry all.  Fixed now.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what you're trying to do, could you maybe post example input and output (for some smaller size data)?

Comment: What formula are you using to arrive at those numbers? I can't seem to reproduce them with any normal correlation/covariance formulas (but then I'm no expert in statistics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing that I could find was using the scipy.stats package

```
In [8]: x
Out[8]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [-1. ,  0. , -1. ],
       [-2. ,  0. , -2. ],
       [-3. ,  0. , -3. ],
       [-4. ,  0.1, -4. ]])
In [9]: y
Out[9]: 
array([[0. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. ],
       [2. , 0. ],
       [3. , 0. ],
       [4. , 0.1]])

In [10]: import scipy.stats

In [27]: (scipy.stats.cov(y,x)
          /(numpy.sqrt(scipy.stats.var(y,axis=0)[:,numpy.newaxis]))
          /(numpy.sqrt(scipy.stats.var(x,axis=0))))
Out[27]: 
array([[-1.        ,  0.70710678, -1.        ],
       [-0.70710678,  1.        , -0.70710678]])
```

These aren't the numbers you got, but you've mixed up your rows.  (Element [0,0] should be 1.)

A more complicated, but purely numpy solution is

```
In [40]: numpy.corrcoef(x.T,y.T)[numpy.arange(x.shape[1])[numpy.newaxis,:]
                                 ,numpy.arange(y.shape[1])[:,numpy.newaxis]]
Out[40]: 
array([[-1.        ,  0.70710678, -1.        ],
       [-0.70710678,  1.        , -0.70710678]])
```

This will be slower because it computes the correlation of each element in x with each other element in x, which you don't want.  Also, the advanced indexing techniques used to get the subset of the array you desire can make your head hurt.

If you're going to use numpy intensely, get familiar with the rules on [broadcasting](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc) and [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).  They will help you push as much down to the C-level as possible.

Comment: I've updated the question with the "right" inputs -- prob. makes sense to update the response just so as not to confuse people :-)

Comment: Done.  I've also added links to some helpful documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do what you want?

```
correlations = dot(transpose(a), b)
```

Note: if you do this, you'll probably want to standardize or whiten `a` and `b` first, e.g. something equivalent to this:

```
a = sqrt((a - mean(a))/(var(a)))
b = sqrt((b - mean(b))/(var(b)))
```

Comment: This could be a much better solution than the accepted answer, just note a, b need to be standardized like a = (a - mean(a))/(var(a))^0.5, and there is a 1/(len(a)-1) coefficient before the dot product. I have seem many answers on stackoverflow treat dot product as correlation, which is mathematically wrong.

Answer (score -1):

As David said, you should define the correlation you're using. I don't know of any definitions of correlation that gives sensible numbers when correlating empty and non-empty signals.